# re substitute with the first group

Tags: python, python-re

I have an expression that I want to extract the first part before the `=` sign. However it doesn't work:

```
import re

re.sub('(.*?)=(.*?)', r'\1', 'F0=None')
```

This returns 'F0None'. Shouldn't it return the first captured group, i.e. 'F0' only?

Comment: But what's the problem with the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.sub` replaces the portion of the string *that matched* with the replacement. Because your second group is also optional (due to the `?`) your pattern is satifsied as soon as the `=` is found, so the rest of the string falls into the "unmatched portion" (i.e. the second group is just a zero-length string). If you make the second group greedy so it grabs the whole rest of the string, it'll work how you expect:

```
>>> re.sub('(.*?)=(.*)', r'\1', 'F0=None')
'F0'
```

Also, if you don't actually want to do anything with it, the second group doesn't need to be a group at all:

```
>>> re.sub('(.*?)=.*', r'\1', 'F0=None')
'F0'
```